# calling post api using webclient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, webclient

I have to call `post` api to generate `token` using `webclient`. I will send `jwt` token in `assertion`. I have got some `example` through net but I dont know how to pass parameters like along with API. can someone help with the same?

I need to call docusign api `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token`

also I need to send `grant_type` and `assertion`. I dont know how to receive this. can someone help with example? below is the image for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxyP9.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build uri with query params you can use [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html)

```java
final WebClient.ResponseSpec response = webClient.post()
      .uri(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token")
        .queryParam("grant_type", "xyz")
        .queryParam("assertion", "anything")
        .toUriString())
      .retrieve();
```

Answer (score 1):

If u are using java then you can use HTTPClient.

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .uri(new URI("url"))
  .headers("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
  .headers("grant_type", "")
  .headers("assertion", "")
  .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("Sample request body"))
  .build();
```

If u are using spring then you can go for webclient. U can set headers like this.

```
webClient.post()
  .uri(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("url").queryParam("assertion", "").queryParam("grant_type", "").toUriString()).retrieve();
```

Hope this helps you to set multiple headers.